# 500 Internal Server Error Apache2 When Opens pdf file

Tags: server, printing, apache2, pdf

I am doing a simple website using cgi technology. I created a domain name called 'www.myexamp.com' . I have given my configurations my website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName      www.myexamp.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myexamp

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
             AllowOverride None
             Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
             Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ok. I can access the cgi files using my domain name 'www.myexamp.com'. For example, When I type URL as 'www.myexamp.com/cgi-bin/hello.cgi' . It gives the correct result. But When I am trying to open some pdf file ('www.myexamp.com/cgi-bin/test.pdf') , It gives me as,

> 500 Internal Server Error Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.myexamp.com Port 80

Should I configure my site configuration file to read pdf. files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**ScriptAlias manual**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias):

> The ScriptAlias directive has the same behavior as the Alias
>   directive, except that in addition it marks the target directory as
>   containing CGI scripts that will be processed by mod_cgi's cgi-script
>   handler.

and in [**mod_cgi manual**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cgi.html):

> Any file that has the handler cgi-script will be treated as a CGI
>   script, and run by the server, with its output being returned to the
>   client. Files acquire this handler either by having a name containing
>   an extension defined by the AddHandler directive, or by being in a
>   ScriptAlias directory.

So you should change path of your `test.pdf` file, for example, try to `mv` it in `DocumentRoot` path:

```
 mv /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.pdf /var/www/myexamp/test.pdf
```